# how can I fixed the Jmodelica compiling error?

Tags: compilation, modelica, dymola, jmodelica

I am trying to compile a Modelica model (built in Dymola) using Jmodelica, but got the following error:

> Compiler arguments:
> Generating code...
>
> ====== Model compiled successfully =======
> OU44_ZoneR2C2_funcs.o:OU44_ZoneR2C2_funcs.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to 'ModelicaStandardTables_CombiTable1D_minimumAbscissa'
>
> OU44_ZoneR2C2_funcs.o:OU44_ZoneR2C2_funcs.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to 'ModelicaStandardTables_CombiTable1D_maximumAbscissa'
> OU44_ZoneR2C2_funcs.o:OU44_ZoneR2C2_funcs.c:(.text+0x1e7): undefined reference to 'ModelicaStandardTables_CombiTable1D_init2'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> mingw32-make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmje1.png): *** [fmume20_] Error 1
> mingw32-make: *** [fmume20] Error 2
> "C:/Users/taoy/AppData/Roaming/JModelica.org-2.14/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make" -f "C:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\Makefiles\MakeFile" "PLATFORM_FLAG=-m64" "RUNTIMELIBRARY_LIB_DIR=C:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/lib/RuntimeLibrary64" "MINPACK_LIB_DIR=C:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/Minpack/lib64" "SUNDIALS_LIB_DIR=C:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\ThirdParty\Sundials/lib64" "WINPTHREADS_LIB_DIR=C:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/winpthreads/lib/winpthreads64" fmume20_
>
> mingw32-make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmje1.png): Entering directory 
> 'C:/Users/taoy/AppData/Local/Temp/1/jmc7241264750773945049out'
> "gcc" -m64  -std=c89 -pedantic -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -O1 "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/include/RuntimeLibrary" "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/FMI/2.0"  "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\ThirdParty\Sundials/include" -c -o "OU44_ZoneR2C2_funcs.o" sources/OU44_ZoneR2C2_funcs.c
> "gcc" -m64  -std=c89 -pedantic -msse2 -mfpmath=sse "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/include/RuntimeLibrary" "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/FMI/2.0"  "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\ThirdParty\Sundials/include" -c -o "OU44_ZoneR2C2_init_independent.o" sources/OU44_ZoneR2C2_init_independent.c
> "gcc" -m64  -std=c89 -pedantic -msse2 -mfpmath=sse "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/include/RuntimeLibrary" "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/FMI/2.0"  "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\ThirdParty\Sundials/include" -c -o "OU44_ZoneR2C2_init_dependent.o" sources/OU44_ZoneR2C2_init_dependent.c
> "gcc" -m64  -std=c89 -pedantic -msse2 -mfpmath=sse "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/include/RuntimeLibrary" "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/FMI/2.0"  "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\ThirdParty\Sundials/include" -c -o "OU44_ZoneR2C2_base.o" sources/OU44_ZoneR2C2_base.c
> "gcc" -m64  -std=c89 -pedantic -msse2 -mfpmath=sse "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/include/RuntimeLibrary" "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/FMI/2.0"  "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\ThirdParty\Sundials/include" -c -o "OU44_ZoneR2C2_equ.o" sources/OU44_ZoneR2C2_equ.c
> "gcc" -m64  -std=c89 -pedantic -msse2 -mfpmath=sse "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/include/RuntimeLibrary" "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/FMI/2.0"  "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\ThirdParty\Sundials/include" -c -o "OU44_ZoneR2C2_equ_init.o" sources/OU44_ZoneR2C2_equ_init.c
> "gcc" -m64  -std=c89 -pedantic -msse2 -mfpmath=sse "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/include/RuntimeLibrary" "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/FMI/2.0"  "-IC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\ThirdParty\Sundials/include" -c -o "OU44_ZoneR2C2.o" sources/OU44_ZoneR2C2.c 
> mkdir binaries\win64
> "C:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\MinGW\bin\g++" -m64 -shared -m64   -o "binaries/win64/OU44_ZoneR2C2.dll"  OU44_ZoneR2C2_funcs.o  OU44_ZoneR2C2_init_independent.o  OU44_ZoneR2C2_init_dependent.o  OU44_ZoneR2C2_base.o  OU44_ZoneR2C2_equ.o  OU44_ZoneR2C2_equ_init.o  OU44_ZoneR2C2.o  "-LC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/lib/RuntimeLibrary64" -lfmi2              -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -ljmi "-LC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/lib" -L"C:\Users\taoy\Documents\Modelica Standard Library 3.2.3\Modelica 3.2.3\Resources\Library/win64/gcctdm510" -L"C:\Users\taoy\Documents\Modelica Standard Library 3.2.3\Modelica 3.2.3\Resources\Library/win64" -L"C:\Users\taoy\Documents\Modelica Standard Library 3.2.3\Modelica 3.2.3\Resources\Library" -lModelicaStandardTables -lModelicaIO -lModelicaMatIO -lzlib -lModelicaExternalC -ljmi_get_set_default -lModelicaStandardTables -lModelicaIO -lModelicaMatIO -lzlib -lModelicaExternalC -ljmi_get_set_default -llapack -lblas -l:libgfortran.a -l:libquadmath.a -lModelicaExternalC -lzlib -ljmi "-LC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\ThirdParty\Sundials/lib64" -l:libsundials_kinsol.a -l:libsundials_nvecserial.a -l:libsundials_cvode.a "-LC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/Minpack/lib64" -l:libcminpack.a "-LC:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install/ThirdParty/winpthreads/lib/winpthreads64" -l:libwinpthread.a
> C:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\Makefiles\MakeFile:214: recipe for target 'fmume20_' failed
> mingw32-make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmje1.png): Leaving directory 'C:/Users/taoy/AppData/Local/Temp/1/jmc7241264750773945049out'
> C:\Users\taoy\AppData\Roaming\JModelica.org-2.14\install\Makefiles\MakeFile:210: recipe for target 'fmume20' failed 
> Unknown program error, org.jmodelica.util.exceptions.CcodeCompilationException: Compilation of generated C code failed.
> C file location: C:\Users\taoy\AppData\Local\Temp\1\jmc7241264750773945049out\sources\OU44_ZoneR2C2.c

[image]

It says model compiled successfully, but the error occurs afterwards. I looked into model, if I delete the model component "CombiTable1D from Modelica standard Library", then the error is fixed. Seems likt something is wrong with this component. However, this component is necessasy in my model.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Can you try to compile with Visual Studio instead of gcc? MSL tables use external code, I think.

Comment: Do you mean using compiler visual studio in Jmodelica? but how can I set it, I am able to compile using visual studio in Dymola.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ModelicaStandardTables_CombiTable1D_minimumAbscissa` was added in 2017, but JModelica uses a 2016 version of the MSL C-sources:
https://github.com/JModelica/JModelica/blob/8982e1f4e7ca33b01b398f389b73d2398761ee9c/ThirdParty/MSL/Modelica/Resources/C-Sources/ModelicaStandardTables.c

You likely need to use an earlier version of the Modelica Standard Library (3.2.2 is included with JModelica), or a different Modelica tool since JModelica is discontinued.

Comment: Thank you very much, the compiling now works with Modelica 3.2.2